# Footer not hiding on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide my footer for small devices and screens. Any thoughts on how I could do so?  I had tried:

`<div class="hidden-xs">`  and

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Which were popular solutions online, but no luck. My code is below:

**HTML**

```html
<footer>
    <div class="copyright"><p>Copyright; url 2021</p></div>
    <div class="location">Footer text</div>
    <div class="contact">WhatsUp@url.com</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-style: 1px thin solid red;
}
```

Comment: Use class on footer

`<footer class="d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block d-sm-none d-xs-none">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **bootstrap**, you can add this class `d-block d-sm-none`

```
<footer class="d-block d-sm-none">
    ...
</footer>
```

Or you can remove the `.` on your **css**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Or add `class="footer"` on your **html**

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
    ...
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not hiding actual footer, but a div with a `.footer` class, which does not exist in your case.

Try this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   footer {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="copyright"><p>Copyright; url 2021</p></div>
    <div class="location">Footer text</div>
    <div class="contact">WhatsUp@url.com</div>
</footer>
```

Now you are hiding a `footer` element.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.` from `.footer` css class

You use `footer` tag directly in css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    footer {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Or add `class="footer"` to `footer` tag